# TSQL 2008r2 Change Index to Index Seek Not Index Scan

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

MS SQL Server 2008r2

I need the following to Index Seek and not Index Scan.
Also, if someone can explain why it isn't Seeking that would be appreciated.

Here's my table

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LogTbl') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #LogTbl
    CREATE TABLE #LogTbl(
         rNum       INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,LogID      INT NOT NULL
        ,NodeID     INT NOT NULL
        ,GPSTime    INT NOT NULL
        ,Speed      INT NULL
        ,RoadSpeed  INT NULL
        ,DriverNodeID INT NULL
        ,Category   VARCHAR(10)
        ,Points     INT     
        ,CatPoints  INT
    )
    ALTER TABLE #LogTbl ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_LogTbl1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( rNum )
```

Here's my NonClustered Indexes

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Log1 ON #LogTbl( RoadSpeed )
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Log2 ON #LogTbl( rNum ) INCLUDE ( RoadSpeed, Speed )
```

This query will Index Seek on IDX_Log1

```
    UPDATE #LogTbl SET RoadSpeed = 0 WHERE RoadSpeed IS NULL
```

But this one only Index Scan on IDX_Log2

```
    UPDATE L
    SET RoadSpeed = CASE
                        WHEN L.RoadSpeed = 0 THEN 70
                        ELSE ROUND( L.RoadSpeed  * 0.621371192, 0 )
                    END
            ,Speed = ROUND( L.Speed  * 0.621371192, 0 )
    FROM #LogTbl L
```

[image: Index Scan On IDX_Log2]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you want a seek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply there is nothing to Seek. Your first query has a where clause:

```
WHERE RoadSpeed IS NULL;
```

Since you have a nonclustered index on `RoadSpeed` the optimiser can seek the null rows in this index. In your second query you have no where clause and need to update the entire table, therefore a scan of all rows must be performed.

For what it is worth, your nonclustered index on `rnum` is most likely redundant:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Log2 ON #LogTbl( rNum ) INCLUDE ( RoadSpeed, Speed )
```

This is the clustering key, so is already indexed, and the columns `RoadSpeed`, and `Speed` are included (since the clustered index is the data). Your second nonclustered index is basically a duplicate of this index, but narrower because you only have 3 columns of data to store. If your have very few read/writes, and frequently use just these three columns, then the index may be worth while, but in the majority of cases the cost of maintaining this additional index, will outweigh the slight performance benefit it offers.

Comment: Thanks @GarethD. Another scenaria, same table. What if you were to update #LogTbl with an inner join on another table? Will an index on the join condition not help?

Comment: Probably, although it still depends, how and when certain decisions are made by the optimiser is hugely complex, and it is very difficult to make generic statements like "an index on the join condition will improve query performance", each individual query, and set of data really needs to be treated on it's own merits.